# Open XML: Get absolute coordinates a child shape

Tags: c#, xml, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

*Sorry for my English.*

A PowerPoint slide contains a **group shape** (grpSp) with following coordinates:

```
<a:off y="2058985" x="244799"/>
<a:ext cy="2264343" cx="7118946"/>
<a:chOff y="2058986" x="244799"/>
<a:chExt cy="1942187" cx="5727249"/>
```

This group shape contains a **child shape** (sp) with following coordinates:

```
<a:off y="3084512" x="244799"/>
<a:ext cy="916661" cx="1710237"/>
```

After ungrouping the child shape contains follow coordinates:

```
<a:off y="2058986" x="244799"/>
<a:ext cy="1064224" cx="2545581"/>
```

As you can see coordinates are changed - converting to **absolute coordinate** on the slide.

I cannot programmatically to make the formula to get these absolutely coordinates. Which formula should I use to convert a child shape's coordinates to absolute as shown in the example (cx="1710237" => 
"2545581")?

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with this and then I found some documentation that was helpful here
http://officeopenxml.com/drwSp-outline.php

I beleive those values must be divided by 12700
x / 12700 = **Answer**
y / 12700 = **Answer**